# Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Core requires the Visual Web Developer feature to be installed in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: azure

i'm trying to install WindowsAzureTools.vs110.exe on mu Windows 7 PC. I have Visual studio 2012 Ultimate installed. The installation of WindowsAzureTools.vs110.exe ends with fatal error: Fatal Error 0x80070643. In the log file there is nothing interesting, but in the event log there is error:

> Product: Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Core --
>   Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Core requires the
>   Visual Web Developer feature to be installed in Visual Studio 2012
>   (Professional or above).

can somebody help what I'm missing?

I have installed full version of VS2012 with all components.

thanks

Comment: correct answer with no upvote? I'll add one just out of principle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try installing the full package for Visual Studio instead? Link: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=254364&clcid=0x409

And for the manual installation you have to know that there are 2 download pages, maybe you downloaded it from the wrong page:

- [Windows Azure SDK for .NET - June 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29988) -> You need this one if you use VS2012 RC
- [Windows Azure SDK for .NET - June 2012 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30651) -> You need this one if you use VS2012 RTM